# Newton-Raphson Method and the Van der Waal Equation Coding question

Tags: equation-solving, chemistry

So I need to find Specific Volumes using the Newton Method from the Van der Waal equation over a change of constant Temperature but variant Pressure.

I have been able to make a list of however many iterations of the altered Van der Waal equation for the root finding method from Pressure Min to Pressure Max (3.9atm to 59.2atm).  Further, I am able to select one element/expression from that list and find the root/Specific Volume for that iteration.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make a list of all the Specific Volumes, ie solve for the root in more than one expression at a time.

This is my code solving for the 10th element in the list (about 12.2atm):

---

a = 1.36;

b = .003183;

R = .0820578;

T = 333;

inc = (59.2 - 3.9)/60;

c = Table[
  vi - ((((atm) + (a/vi^2)) (vi - b) - (R*T))/((atm) - (a/
         vi^2) + (2 a*b/vi^3))), {atm, 3.9, 59.2, inc}]

FindRoot[c[[10]] == 0, {vi, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

---

The output:

---

```
{-((-27.3252 + (3.9 + 1.36/vi^2) (-0.003183 + vi))/(
   3.9 + 0.00865776/vi^3 - 1.36/vi^2)) + 
  vi,

 -((-27.3252 + (4.82167 + 1.36/vi^2) (-0.003183 + vi))/(
   4.82167 + 0.00865776/vi^3 - 1.36/vi^2)) + 
  vi, 

-((-27.3252 + (5.74333 + 1.36/vi^2) (-0.003183 + vi))/(
   5.74333 + 0.00865776/vi^3 - 1.36/vi^2)) + vi,
```

### AND SO ON.............

Also:

---

```
{vi -> 2.1930639624928306932}
```

---

Which is a correct answer.

I've tried this fix to solve for more than one element in the list(elements one to ten):

---

```
FindRoot[c[[1;;10]] == 0, {vi, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

---

but this yields an error:

---

> FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in FindRoot[c[[1;;10]]==0,{vi,4},WorkingPrecision->20]. >>

---

Any ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm sorry, it's working again for the Van der Waals but neither of the other 2.  No matter how I change the starting point the output now is the same, odd number repeated and I don't know how to manipulate either FindMinimum nor Foldlist to change that.

### My code is

```
R = 8.314;
A = 507.28;
B = 0.10476;
a = 0.07132;
b = 0.07235;
c = 660000;
T = 333;
iter = 60;

FX = -P - (A (1 - a/v))/v^2 + (R T (1 - c/(T^3 v)) (B (1 - b/v) + v))/
   v^2;
FXX = -((a A)/v^4) + (2 A (1 - a/v))/v^3 + (
   R T (1 + (b B)/v^2) (1 - c/(T^3 v)))/v^2 + (
   c R (B (1 - b/v) + v))/(T^2 v^4) - (
   2 R T (1 - c/(T^3 v)) (B (1 - b/v) + v))/v^3;

FXXX = v - FX/FXX;

nn = Table[FXXX, {P, 400, 6000, iter}];

Ps = Table[P, {P, 400, 6000, iter}]

vs = Rest@FoldList[v /. Last@FindMinimum[#2, {v, #1}] &, 12, nn]

ListPlot[Thread[{Ps, vs}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

---

### The output is

```
{1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77,
  1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 
 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77, 1.3665*10^77}
```

---

I'm sorry I basically know nothing haha, but I need this done and I just don't know how to do it.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: May I suggest you to rewrite the equation of state in terms of the compressibility factor (Z=PV/RT). This reduces the equation of state to a cubic ploynomial the roots of which are easy to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve a list of equations separately, you could just use `Table` again:

```
Table[FindRoot[c[[i]] == 0, {vi, 4}], {i, Length@c}]
```

Or without an index:

```
Table[FindRoot[eq == 0, {vi, 4}], {eq, c}]
```

Or you could `Map` a function over your list:

```
FindRoot[# == 0, {vi, 4}]& /@ c
```

But I'm not so sure it's the root you are after.  If you plot one of your functions:

```
Plot[c[[10]], {vi, 0, 10}]
```

What you are finding is actually a local minimum:

[image: c10minimum]

because the root finding is getting stuck there.

If that's what you are really after, you should probably be using `FindMinimum` instead of `FindRoot`.  In any case, you are probably going to have problems with the initial starting point.

*Edit*:  After a bit of messing around, perhaps this is what you are after:

```
atms = Table[atm, {atm, 3.9, 59.2, inc}];
vis = Table[vi /. Last@FindMinimum[c[[i]], {vi, 7 i^(-1/2) - 0.5}], {i, Length@c}];
ListPlot[Thread[{atms, vis}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

[image: viatm]

*Edit 2*: A better way to apply starting conditions is just to use the result from the previous minimum.  Starting with 7 for the first minimum, `FoldList` allows you to pass this on to each successive minimisation.

```
vis = Rest@FoldList[vi /. Last@FindMinimum[#2, {vi, #1}] &, 7, c];
```

Comment: This works!  Thanks so much.  How did you find the starting condition?  The 7i^-.5 - .5 ? I'm trying to apply this method to two other equations, Ideal Gas Law and the Beattie Bridgeman but I can't get it working.

Comment: Starting conditions were found by trial and error: minimise with a starting value function, plot the results, make up a new function that approximates the good bits of the plot, repeat.  See the edit for a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's working again for the Van der Waals but neither of the other 2.  No matter how I change the starting point the output now is the same, odd number repeated and I don't know how to manipulate either FindMinimum nor Foldlist to change that.

Comment: I've made an edit with the new code and output for the Beattie-Bridgeman

Comment: Looks like you actually want a root this time instead of the minimum.  Change `FindMinimum` back to `FindRoot`.  Also don't forget to adjust your `PlotRange`.